# Is the time represented in ticks or seconds in /proc/stat, /proc/uptime and /proc/[pid]/stat accurate or approximate

Tags: java, linux

`man proc`:"/proc/stat:idle Time spent in the idle task.  This value should be USER_HZ times the second entry  in the /proc/uptime pseudo-file."

But I found that there was a slight discrepancy between the two. Further, to my way of thinking, the sum of the first row of /proc/stat, CPU ticks, should be equal to the uptime times USER_HZ times the number of cores, and be equal to the start_time fields in /proc/self/stat times the number of cores when a process starts.

There is a simple code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class TestTick{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(calTotTicks()/12.0/calSelfStartTime());
        System.out.println(12.0*uptime()*100/calTotTicks());
        System.out.println(calIdleTicks()/100/idleTime());
        System.out.println(calSelfStartTime()/100/uptime());
    }

    private static long calTotTicks(){
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/stat"));
            String stat=reader.readLine();
            String[] stats = stat.split("\\s+");
            long tot = 0;
            for(int i=1;i<stats.length;++i)
                tot += Long.parseLong(stats[i]);
            return tot;
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private static long calIdleTicks(){
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/stat"));
            String[] stats = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
            return Long.parseLong(stats[4]);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private static long calSelfStartTime(){
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/self/stat"));
            String[] stats = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
            return Long.parseLong(stats[21]);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private static double uptime(){
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/uptime"));
            String stat = reader.readLine();
            String[] stats = stat.split("\\s+");
            return Double.parseDouble(stats[0]);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return 0.0;
    }

    private static double idleTime(){
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/uptime"));
            String[] stats = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
            return Double.parseDouble(stats[1]);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

My computer is with Linux version 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft 12 cores, and the USER_HZ is 100. The result of one run is

```
1.0018526913814474
0.9981444139842264
1.0077164731297508
0.9999877709392094
```

The results of multiple runs vary and they all seem to be close to 1, but the difference in absolute numbers is huge. So is the tick nums in these files are not accurate, or maybe I'm wrong.

Thank you all for any help!

Comment: Be aware that you are not reading these files atomically - you read one after the other, creating multiple Objects along the way. Each of these method calls certainly takes lots of CPU cycles, and you call them multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it does not solve all questions. Assume that when the process starts, `calIdleTicks() = 100 * idleTime()`, while the program returns `calIdleTicks() - 100 * idleTime() = 201912`, that means there is an error of about 168 seconds, which is impossible. @Hulk